# Search viewer model by attribute names

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I followed this [Search demo](http://the360view.typepad.com/blog/2015/07/lab5-view-and-data-api-intro-get-properties-and-search.html), and am trying to expand it to only search on specified attribute names.

It works without an attribute name, and returns an array of matching ids.  But if I supply anything for the attribute name then search returns an empty array.  I am guessing I need some magic formating for the attribute name.

So currently I have:

```
function search() {
    var txtArea = document.getElementById("TextAreaResult");
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("SearchString").value;
    var searchProperties = document.getElementById("SearchProperties").value;

    if (searchStr.length == 0) {
        txtArea.value = "no search string.";
        return;
    }

    var viewer = viewerApp.getCurrentViewer();
    viewer.clearSelection();

    if (searchProperties.length == 0)
        viewer.search(searchStr, searchCallback, searchErrorCallback);
    else {
        var searchPropList = searchProperties.split(',');
        viewer.search(searchStr, searchCallback, searchErrorCallback, searchPropList);
    }
}
```

where searchProperties is a user input, eg "Name", and searchPropList becomes a single element array.

The same example also covers getProperties(), which returns displayName and displayCategory for each property, but I don't see a separate internal name.

Am I missing something obvious [from here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) or do I need to transform "Name" in some way.

Or does someone have an example that will list the true name rather than displayName?

Comment: I'm investigating this, but it seems the 'attributeNames' param is case sensitive, can you try on your end?

Comment: So the search works with searchProperties='name', I still can't pick up the custom properties.

Searching for "No", "no", or "nO" without an attribute name picks up lots of ids, and highlights "Hidden" and "Required" in the property panel.
But adding "Hidden", "hidden", "Required" or "required" as the attribute each returned empty.

Comment: So if "name" works, and "Name" does not, yet the property displayName is "Name", is there an internal "name" that gets reported as "Name"?

Answer (score 0):

The [Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D.search()](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/) method is NOT case sensitive on the **text** parameter, but it IS case sensitive on the **attributeNames** parameter, and you need to use the full name of the attribute.

We're now (Aug, 25, 2016) updating the documentation.

Comment: Is there an example to get the full name of a property from [getProperties](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/model/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) or similar?

Or should the full name match the returned displayName?

Comment: Sorry I missed this: viewer.getProperties() is currently returning the displayName. When there is no displayName, then (and only then) attribute name is returned.